# Woocommerce thank you page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to know where to put my google tracking code. I need to place it on the ‘Thank You’ page to track conversions. That page isn’t in the ‘Pages’ tab in the wordpress dashboard, so I’m a bit unclear as to where I put it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks very much.

Comment: You might try asking in the [Wordpress Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use woocommerce `woocommerce_thankyou` hook to achieve this.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_thankyou_code' );

function custom_thankyou_code() {
    ?>
    <script>
    //paste your js here
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: i simply want to add google tracking JS code in the <head> of that page

Comment: I have updated my answer, this solution will add a script to the page content, not the header, but that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: one last thing, is there anyway to know the success page url?

Comment: what is success page? where do you want to access its url?

Comment: so once the user has purchased something, they should be directed to a thank you page of some sort?